# finding MAC address from a remote computer using a private IP

Tags: mac, security, ip

I want to know the MAC address of a device from a remote computer. I also want to know the security threats if somebody knows my MAC address?

Comment: The question about security threats is actually a fairly long answer if answered correctly.  It's better off as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know the MAC address of a device from a remote computer.

Log into that remove computer and use 'arp -a' or log into the local switch and issue its command to display ARP values (the command varies per brand and per model).

> I also want to know the security threats if somebody knows my MAC address?

There is no security threat if someone knows your MAC. MACs are used locally only.

Noone who is not on the same local network (read: in most cases none who is not in your home plugged into the same switch or connected to the same wireless network) can do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

use

> arp -a 192.168.0.1

or whatever is the IP of the machine that needs to be traced

Answer (score 0):

To find out the MAC address of a machine:

- if you have access to the machine, run `ipconfig /all`

  (windows - look under "Physical Address") or `ifconfig` (Linux - look under HWaddr)
- If you don't have access to the machine but have access to a machine on the same lan, then ping the target machine. Afterwards, run `arp -a` (both windows and linux). This will show you the mapping of IP to MAC.
- If you're not on the same LAN and don't have access to the machine, then you're out of luck.

Now, about the security concerns, the only information contained in the MAC address is an ID of the manufacturer of the network card. This is because of the way in which MAC addresses are allocated. The IEEE, which allocates MAC addresses, gives each manufacturer a three byte prefix. The other three bytes in a MAC address are set by the manufacturer himself. So given a MAC address, you can look [here](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt) and find out who made the card that carries that MAC. For example, network interface cards with a MAC starting with 00-26-98 are made by Cisco.

Answer (score 0):

### Getting a (remote) MAC Address

You can either collect the MAC address from that computer using the network configuration utilities or commands like `ifconfig` (Linux/Unix/Mac) or `ipconfig /all` (Windows).

From a remote computer, you have to be on the same broadcast network as the computer you want to know the MAC address of. Then you can use utilities like `arp -a` to find other devices on your network.

### Security Concerns

An attacker outside of your network can not do anything with your MAC address, besides knowing what kind of network hardware you have. This does not really expose much.

If an attacker is on your local network, and knows your MAC address (which is just public knowledge), he can use this for malign purposes.

If the attacker just configures his MAC address on his machine, and joins the network with it, you will see a MAC address collision. The other machines in the network will then have a hard time figuring out where to send data to. Both the attacker and the victim will then not be able to do much in terms of setting up connections. Both machines will send errors back about connections not initiated by the themselves, closing those connections.

A complicated attack is that the attacker configures the MAC address on his machine and sends no (active) data himself. The data sent to your computer will then also be sent to the attackers computer. This is fairly complicated to set up, because the attacker has to prevent data from being sent at a very low level. Otherwise connections will be reset, and the victim will notice all kinds of strange connection errors.

An even more complicated attack is possible on wireless networks, where an attacker could possibly eavesdrop on both the incoming and outgoing connections. This requires wireless network hardware that allows MAC address changing, and also depends on both positions relative to the base station.

## TL;DR

Just make sure you use encrypted connections when you're using WiFi, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, then use:

```
nbtstat -A <ip-address>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know the MAC address of a device from a remote computer.

You're out of luck unless you're on the same physical network as the remote computer - e.g. can you log into another system on the same network, or perhaps the network's router.

If two machines with Ethernet interfaces have spoken IPv4 on the same network, the MAC address will be in the system's ARP cache, which you can check with the `arp` command (generally any desktop/server OS with TCP/IP will have some form of this command).  Some systems have `arping` which lets you issue an ARP request directly on the network.

> I also want to know the security threats if somebody knows my MAC address?

If the attacker is outside of your network, not too much other than knowing the manufacturer of your NIC.

If the attacker is inside your network, he/she can perform ARP spoofing, which can facilitiate the following types of attacks on IPv4 communications (excerpt from [this article](https://www.veracode.com/security/arp-spoofing)):

> - Denial-of-service attacks: DoS attacks often leverage ARP spoofing to
>     link multiple IP addresses with a single target’s MAC address. As a
>     result, traffic that is intended for many different IP addresses will
>     be redirected to the target’s MAC address, overloading the target with
>     traffic.
> - Session hijacking: Session hijacking attacks can use ARP spoofing to
>     steal session IDs, granting attackers access to private systems and
>     data.
> - Man-in-the-middle attacks: MITM attacks can rely on ARP spoofing to
>     intercept and modify traffic between victims.